# Проверить значение из нескольких колонок датафрейма на наличие в другом датафрейме

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, валидация

Есть два датафрейма

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {
       "col1": ["string1", "dd", "string2", {"name": "first_name", "dec": "description 102"}],
       "col2": [{"name": "last_name", "dec": "description 103"}, "string1", np.nan, "string2"],
       "col3": ["string1", {"name": "last_name", "dec": "description 103"}, "gg", "string33", ],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "string": ["string1", "string2"],
        "name": ["first_name", "last_name"],
        "desc": ["description 102", "description 103"]
    }
)
```

нужно провести валидацию первого датафрейма, и оставить те строки, в которых каждое значение валидно.
Вылидные они, если значение совпадает с колонкой `df2.string` или значение-словарь совпадает с парой из `df2[["name", "desc"]]`

В голову приходит решение только писать кастомную функцию, которая будет итерироваться по строкам и просматривать каждое значение из колонки. Можно ли как-то использовать `apply()` метод, чтобы это было более по **pandas**`овски?

Для сравнения словаря использовал

```
value in df2[["name", "desc"]].to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если навскидку, то вам как раз придется избавляться от словарей, потому что они - нехешируемый тип данных.

Вероятнее всего, у вас будет работать подобная конструкция:

```
masker = df1.applymap(lambda x: tuple(x.values()) if type(x)==dict else x)
res= df1[masker.isin(list(df2["string"].values)) | masker.isin(list(map(tuple, df2[["name", "desc"]].values.tolist())))]
```

Ваш пример, однако, непоказателен, потому что по вашему же условию, все его строки попадут в результат.

Comment: Спасибо, да, пример кривоват(исправил), но в результат они попадут по-любому все, просто надо потом еще вызвать метод ```dropna()```, тогда останутся только валидные строки